# Owl Carousel appears vertical instead of horizontal and owl-item is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have a owl Carousel implemented on Page Load and 2 items appear at once as expected.However I have a google map showing dealer location on click of the dealer the item should get added in the second spot.I just use splice and want to make it appear with the added item.So I pass the array through the same logic of adding item as I did earlier I observe that the carousel appears vertically instead of horizontally showing one item.Can you please suggest how to refresh the carousel to  make it appear as before.

```
var navBarLi;
    var navBarHtml;
    if(apz.PostLo.DealerDetails.bkpnavBarLiHtml && apz.PostLo.DealerDetails.bkpNavBarLi){

            navBarLi = apz.PostLo.DealerDetails.bkpNavBarLi;
            navBarHtml = apz.PostLo.DealerDetails.bkpnavBarLiHtml;


    }
    else{

     navBarLi = $("#PostLo__DealerDetails__ps_pls_7");

     apz.PostLo.DealerDetails.bkpNavBarLi = navBarLi;
     navBarHtml = navBarLi.html();
     apz.PostLo.DealerDetails.bkpnavBarLiHtml = navBarHtml;

    }

    const arrayOfNavBarLi = array.reduce((p,n)=>{
        p += navBarHtml;
        return p;
    }
    , "");

    navBarLi.html(arrayOfNavBarLi);


    array.forEach((object, index) => {

        for (key in object) {
            apz.PostLo.DealerDetails.manualBinding_assignValue(object, index, key,navBarLi);
        }
    }) 

    navBarLi.owlCarousel({
        navigation: true,
        items: 2,
        center: true,
        margin: 0,
        lazyLoad: true,
        dots: true
    });

    navBarLi.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

The above code reads the component and makes a copy of html and element and  it iterates as per array elements.The single form contains elements with same id elements.The component calls the owl carousel on load.
      On click of dealer on the map the element declared globally is reassigned to a variable and its html content.The content is iterated as before and assigned again to owl-carousel.The carousel appears vertically instead of horizontally.Please guide me.